# Cocos2d 2.0 Adding UIView to CClayer openglview deprecated

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, deprecated, cclayer

I'm having some troubles adding an UIView to cocos2d v2.0 since the openGlView is deprecated I can't add the view to it. I was looking around to find another way to do this but I couldn't find anything.

Can anyone tell me the new way to add an UIView in front of all cc layers?? or how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this instead of openGLView:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, but I don't think I can use this. What I want is to add a custom keyboard wich is a subclass of UIView into my main layer (CCLayer). I currently have the deprecated method working but I want to remove all warnings.

Comment: Just add the UIView to the window then, that would be the easiest way. If that doesn't work I think there are other workarounds for adding UIViews.

Comment: but to access the window I need to use openGlView which is deprecated. Guess I'll keep looking. Thank you XD

Comment: Also ccGLView is the new API for openGLView so this is specifically what you are looking for.

Comment: But what if you want to bring cocos2d view to the front? how would you accomplish that?

Comment: @JuanPabloBoero Not sure what you mean. Its the same as before just reference the view using CCDirector's view and just make your other subviews all behind that.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me!

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myUiView];

Considering that openGLView is deprecated!